# Error Build PhoneGap(Cordova-1.5) With Visual Studio 2010 - Error : The command "CScript" exited with code 9009

Tags: windows-phone-7, cordova

I need your help please. 
I try to create a demo mobile application for windows phone 7  With PhoneGap ( Cordova-1.5)
I follow all the instruction that mention in the [Get Started Guide](http://phonegap.com/start#wp) at PhoneGap web site :
I install the [windows phone sdk 7.1](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=27570)
I download phonegap zip file

I extract the zip file and copy the Cordova-1.5.0-Starter.zip file from the:
phonegap-phonegap-1.5.0-0-gde1960d\phonegap-phonegap-de1960d\lib\windows\Cordova-1.5.0-Starter.zip

To [USERNAME]\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Templates\ProjectTemplates\Silverlight for Windows Phone

According the instructions.

When i build the project i get an error :

> Error 1   The command "CScript "D:\DOT.NET\Demo
>   Applications\CordovaStarter2\CordovaStarter2/BuildManifestProcessor.js"
>   "D:\DOT.NET\Demo
>   Applications\CordovaStarter2\CordovaStarter2\CordovaStarter2.csproj""
>   exited with code
>   9009. C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets  902 9   CordovaStarter2

I try to Uninstall windows phone sdk 7.1 & install it again and i dont understand what i miss ?

I really appreciate your help, please advice.

Answer (score 2):

```
C:\windows\system32\cscript.exe "$(ProjectDir)/BuildManifestProcessor.js" "$(ProjectPath)"
```

works, it seems the build referenced wrong cscript.exe, so change it to

```
C:\windows\system32\cscript.exe could help
```

Comment: Where do you u put this ? I dont understand

Answer (score 1):

edit your project file and change this:

```
<PreBuildEvent>CScript "$(ProjectDir)/BuildManifestProcessor.js" "$(ProjectPath)"</PreBuildEvent>
```

to

```
<PreBuildEvent>C:\windows\system32\cscript.exe "$(ProjectDir)/BuildManifestProcessor.js" "$(ProjectPath)"</PreBuildEvent>
```

Comment: I dont understand how to edit the project file like you advice

Comment: Where do you put this? What is the "project file" ?

Answer (score 0):

I would say there's something wrong with at least one of your installations. I just pulled the same version of the Cordova starter template (from https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap/zipball/1.5.0), and followed all the steps which ran the starter project sucessfully.

I'd try re-installing everything. Visual Studio, Windows Phone SDK and download a fresh copy of the starter template.